# get value of image custom field at frontent of wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Please help me out.I am battling since three days.

How to fetch value of a custom field to display it in post content area?

Comment: Image custom field? where do you storing the file info and image. get_post_meta. can help you to bring the value of custom post meta

Comment: Thanks for reply.I added some code in function.php,through which I can see my custom field while am uploading any image and it is retaining those values which I am giving it but what I want is to fetch that custom field value into my post.tried many things but no result.

Comment: first you didn't answer my questions. Have you tried 'get_post_meta'. can you explain what many things you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can get custom field to display using below code:

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

Comment: add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'edit_media_custom_field', 11, 2 );
    add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', 'save_media_custom_field', 11, 2 );
    
    function edit_media_custom_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
        $form_fields['custom_field'] = array( 'label' => 'Product Code', 'input' => 'text', 'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_field', true ) );
        return $form_fields;
    }
    function save_media_custom_field( $post, $attachment ) {
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_custom_field', $attachment['custom_field'] );
        return $post;

Comment: and I want to fetch it in category.php. I am using  
    echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field', true);

Comment: $key: it will be name of your custom field

Comment: $single :If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields.

Comment: but this displays custom field w.r.t to post. I want w.r.t image.Can I?

Comment: Yes, you can pass attachment id

Answer (score 0):

Custom field data can be fetched inside template (inside loop) using this functions:

Fetches all fields

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

OR for specific value

```
get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

You can learn more + examples in official wordpress documentation about [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this through below code:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true); ?>
```

Here your arguments must same as you have mention in function.php, while creating your custom field like  as in:

```
<?php add_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single,true); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: but this displays custom field w.r.t to post. I want w.r.t image.Can I?